# Funky While loop / Funky syntax error Python 2.7

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop

Ive tried several things to fix this loop and it just wont work. As of right now it gives me a syntax error highlighting the quotation mark after the yes in the first print statement... I see nothing wrong with it?

```
Ycount = 0
Ncount = 0
Valid = ["Y","y"]
InValid = ["N","n"]
Quit = ["Q","q"]
Uinp = ""

while Uinp != "Q":
    Uinp = raw_input("Did you answer Y or N to the question(enter Q to quit)? ")
    if Uinp in Valid:
        Ycount = Ycount + 1
        print "You have answered yes" ,Ycount, "times"
        print "You have answered no" ,Ncount, "times"
    elif Uinp in InValid:
        Ncount = Ncount + 1
        print "You have answered yes" ,Ycount, "times"
        print "You have answered no" ,Ncount, "times"
    elif Uinp in Quit:
        break
```

Comment: Well apparently it copied funny too.... the variables are at the end of my comment...

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Comment: What is giving you a syntax error- the highlighting in your editor, or the interpreter when you try to run it?... What version of Python are you using: is it 2.x or a 3.x ?

Comment: I see no syntax errors in that code at all. You would only get a syntax error if this was Python 3.x. Use `2to3` to turn this into Python 3 compatible code.

Comment: I would recommend you to follow [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

Comment: I'll bet that you're actually running the code under 3.x.  Comment out the whole code, and add `import sys` and `print(sys.version)` to the start.

Comment: Well now I am ashamed. It did open with python 3.3 (I learned on 2.7 and I installed 3.3 to learn the differences) so when i reopened it with 2.7 it runs fine. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: The solution to your problem is given by Sammy Arous - the point I make is just good Python practice.**

The preferred, Pythonic way to print out strings with various types in them (in your case, string, followed by int, followed by string, is to use the `.format(*args)` function that operates on strings. In this case, you could use

```
print ("You have answered yes {0} times".format(Ycount))
```

If you want to print out more than one parameter, the first is referenced by `{0}`, the next by '{1}', and so on.

While it's also valid to use the C-esque `%` operator to format stings (e.g. `You have answered yes %d times " % Ycount`, this is not preferred.

Try it with the curly brace syntax. On large projects, it will noticeably make your code faster (compute and print one string, rather than printing three), and is generally more idiomatic with Python.

Comment: While this is useful information - it doesn't address the supposed error the OP has... (most likely they're using version 3.x and need to use `print` as a function, not a statement...)

Answer (score 1):

I have ran your code under python 2 and it worked as expected.

Under python3 however, there are some changes required for you to run it:

`print "something"` is no longer supported, you need to use
`print ("something")`

and `raw_input` was renamed to `input`

```
Ycount = 0
Ncount = 0
Valid = ["Y","y"]
InValid = ["N","n"]
Quit = ["Q","q"]
Uinp = ""

while Uinp != "Q":
    Uinp = input("Did you answer Y or N to the question(enter Q to quit)? ")
    if Uinp in Valid:
        Ycount = Ycount + 1
        print ("You have answered yes" ,Ycount, "times")
        print ("You have answered no" ,Ncount, "times")
    elif Uinp in InValid:
        Ncount = Ncount + 1
        print ("You have answered yes" ,Ycount, "times")
        print ("You have answered no" ,Ncount, "times")
    elif Uinp in Quit:
        break
```